# Why is the "goes" form used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence: "**Microsoft says it's because 40% of search queries on their competitor's site *goes* unanswered - something they can improve on**"

Comment: It's a mistake.

Comment: The "go" form has to be used, right?

Comment: This may be a difference between British and American English but, in British English, "goes" is correct: *of search queries* and *on their competitor's site*can be disregarded as they are only modifiers. Thus the sentence becomes "Microsoft says it's because 40% goes unanswered" and "40 percent" is consider as a single quantity as it has a metric (= percent), e.g. "A million dollars is a lot of money." or "Twenty inches **is** too much - you only need five inches."

Comment: I'm English and would use 'go' to match the count noun-usage 'search queries'. This is perhaps clearer with '14% of men are left-handed'. And despite the above comment, this is standard usage in the UK @Greybeard. [_Generalised Quantifiers_ {ed Gärdenfors}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OnyhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=quasi-partitive&source=bl&ots=4d6n7Ldd7S&sig=ACfU3U0JjNf1ZfYnrsfWhP6noMuiBQzIpg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quasi-partitive&f=false) gives examples of agreement with the partitive usage.